# Quadratic formula: python treating floats as strings

Tags: python, function, concatenation, quadratic, python-cmath

I am making a program that asks the user to input values for a, b and c which are then used to compute the roots using the quadratic formula. The only problem I have is that python treats a and the square root term as two strings and they are not actually added. The + between them is printed out.

Here is my code:

```
import cmath

def cubic_formula(a, b, c):
    print("x1: " + str((-b-cmath.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))/(2*a)))
    print("x2: " + str((-b+cmath.sqrt(b ** 2 - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)))

a = float(input("a: ")) b = float(input("b: ")) c = float(input("c: "))

cubic_formula(a, b, c)
```

And here is the output, illustrating the problem I just described:

[image: screen shot of the output on pycharm]

I don't know how to make it so that the plus-sign results in an actual addition of the two numbers. Removing the str() and having no strings inside print() did not change anything.

Comment: The result is a complex number, the "+" between the 2 numbers indicates the real and imaginary part added together.

Comment: Ah of course, how stupid of me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are witnessing complex numbers, not strings. When the discriminant `b*b-4*a*c` is negative, the solution is not real valued. The imaginary unit is denoted `j` in Python and complexes print like `(a+bj)` in Python.
You may want to check if the discriminant is positive before computing, and use the `math.sqrt` function, which returns a float, instead of the `cmath.sqrt` function, which returns a complex.

Also note you called the function `cubic_formula`, but are calculating `quadratic_formula`.

Answer (score 0):

I split the program into several functions:

- calculation of determinant
- the quadratic formula
- get user input
- print result

And it is fine.

```py
import cmath


def cal_determinant(a, b, c):
    return b * b - 4 * a * c


def quadratic_formula(a, b, c):
    det = cal_determinant(a, b, c)
    sqrt_det = cmath.sqrt(det)
    x1 = (-b - sqrt_det) / (2 * a)
    x2 = (-b + sqrt_det) / (2 * a)
    return x1, x2


def get_user_input():
    coeff_list = []
    for coeff_name in ["a", "b", "c"]:
        v = input(f"{coeff_name}: ")
        v = float(v)
        coeff_list.append(v)
    return coeff_list


def print_roots(x1, x2):
    print(f"x1: {x1}")
    print(f"x2: {x2}")


def main():
    a, b, c = get_user_input()
    x1, x2 = quadratic_formula(a, b, c)
    print_roots(x1, x2)


main()
```